# Retain values before validating UserControl

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a class which is a UserControl:

```
public partial class MyObjectView : System.Windows.Forms.UserControl
```

This interface has various components for user input. To show the issue I'm having, only one is needed to show, so, in MyObjectView.Designer.cs:

```
internal System.Windows.Forms.TextBox txtMyNumber;
```

In the MyObjectView constructor, I have:

```
this.Validating += new System.ComponentModel.CancelEventHandler(this_Validating);
```

and then:

```
private void this_Validating(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs cancelEventArgs)
{

// MyObject here already contains the data entered in the control by the user
}
```

So the user enters data and clicks the close X button in the upper right hand corner. I want to see the difference between what MyObject originally contained (when the UserControl was first displayed) and what the user entered on the form. However, in `this_Validating`, MyObject already has been updated to what the user entered, so I no longer have the 'before'
How do I do this?

Comment: Are you using databinding?

Comment: If you're not using DataBindings, you could have a string type field and assign to this field, in the UC `Load()` event, the current value of the TextBox.Text. Then you can compare and update it both in the `Validating` event of the TextBox and in the `CancelEventHandler` of the UC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you clone the original object in your constructor so you have a copy of it's initial state:

```
    class MyClass
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public MyClass ShallowCopy()
        {
            return (MyClass)this.MemberwiseClone();
        }

    }


    //Copy of original state of object
    private MyClass _orig;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        //In your case this comes in via the constructor?
        MyClass o = new MyClass();
        o.Name = "hi";

        _orig = o.ShallowCopy();
 ...
```

Comment: This works ... one note. I made a copy of the object in OnLoad(), not the constructor.